# When does a prime divide the sum of its primitive roots?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, summation, prime-numbers, primitive-roots

Here :

[Prime numbers primitive roots and $\Phi$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2691208/prime-numbers-primitive-roots-and-phi)

the ratio between the primes dividing the sum of its primitive roots and the primes upto a given limit is asked.

> Is there a nice criterion whether a prime divides the sum of its primitve roots ?

In a comment, it is mentioned that every prime $4k+1$ has the desired property, but there are more primes doing the job. Additionally, can it be proven that the sum of the primtive roots of a prime $p$ must be congruent to $-1,0$ or $1$ modulo $p$ ?

Comment: Primitive roots are defined by the multiplicative structure, why would their *sum* be interesting?

Comment: Isn't the sum just $\mu(p-1)\mod p$? The primitive roots of $p$ are roots of the cyclotomic polynomial $\Phi_{p-1}$, whose sum of roots is the inverse of the coefficient of $x^{\phi(p-1)-1}$, which by induction is $\mu(p-1)$.

Comment: @BobJones Yes, this is the criterion as mentioned by Carl in the linked question.